# How to check whether an array contains elements and form json accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array which is converted to JSON. I want to check if there are any elements in the array, if there are any elements then it should form JSON and if there aren't any then it should store NULL.

```
var json2 = JSON.stringify( { "dataList": values2});
```

where values2 is an array

How can I make this.

Comment: If i get what you want you can say `values2 = (values2.length==0)?null:values2` then assign `values2` to key `dataList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
var json2 = values2.length > 0 ? JSON.stringify({ "dataList": values2 }) : null;
```

Or if you want the `dataList` property to be null:

```
var dataList = values2.length > 0 ? values2 : null,
    json2 = JSON.stringify({ "dataList": dataList });
```

If you want to check if the array has one empty string value, the condition should be:

```
values2.length > 0 && !(values2.length === 1 && values2[0] === '')
```

Comment: I'm getting this, { "dataList": } I want only null

Comment: @user3004356 Then use the first snippet

Comment: I'm getting this for first snippet {"dataList":[""]

Comment: I see the array is taking an empty string for the first textfield. How to check for that

Comment: @user3004356 Do you mean that you want it to be `null` even if the array looks like this `['']`?

Comment: How can I embed this condition along with the rest

Comment: @user3004356 Change `values2.length > 0` to something like `values2.length > 0 && !(values2.length === 1 && values2[0] === '')` to explicitly check for that

Comment: It works, please change the code above. I want to mark the answer

Answer (score 0):

check for its length and based on that create an if/else.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this :

```
    var json2 = values2.length > 0 ? JSON.stringify( { "dataList":values2})
                : JSON.stringify( { "dataList": null}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var json2 = JSON.stringify( { "dataList": (values2.length ? values2 : null) });
```